# How to append multiple values to a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to figure out how to append multiple values to a list in Python. I know there are few methods to do so, such as manually input the values, or put the append operation in a `for` loop, or the `append` and `extend` functions.

However, I wonder if there is neater way to do so? Maybe a certain package or function?

Comment: Have you found the [list documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) yet?

Answer (score 780, accepted):

You can use the [sequence method `list.extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) to extend the list by multiple values from any kind of iterable, being it another list or any other thing that provides a sequence of values.

```
>>> lst = [1, 2]
>>> lst.append(3)
>>> lst.append(4)
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> lst.extend([5, 6, 7])
>>> lst.extend((8, 9, 10))
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

>>> lst.extend(range(11, 14))
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

So you can use `list.append()` to append *a single* value, and `list.extend()` to append *multiple* values.

Comment: A bit complicated to introduce generators to someone on day 1 of using Python.

Comment: @DanielRoseman My point is that the values can come from *any* kind of iterable sequence.

Comment: Note that extend do not keep the structure of the element you add compared to `append()`. With your example using append, you would get `[1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6, 7], (8, 9, 10), range(11, 14)]`. **Python 3**

Comment: @YohanObadia If that was the case for Python 3 in '17, it is no longer the case - Python 3.7.7 does exactly what poke described.

Comment: @YohanObadia That makes no sense.  Append appends ONE ELEMENT, thus it "keeps the structure".  But that's a duh, really.
And @ Post169, nothing change between '17 and today, extend and append still behave the same way, Yohan just didn't understand what's what.

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard I would go even further and say that nothing changed between 2013 and today :D

Answer (score 57):

Other than the `append` function, if by "multiple values" you mean another list, you can simply concatenate them like so.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> a + b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I know this is old, and at the time of writing, 45 people have agreed your answer is good, but strictly speaking the OP asked to add items to a list, and this is creating a new list.  Although a very similar/related statement would be:  a += b.  This would append and be unique from the primary answer above.

Comment: Given `a = [1, 2, 3]`, you can also append multiple elements as `a += [4, 5, 6]`. This sets `a` to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. This does _not_ create a new list; each element is appended to `a`. (Test this with `a = [1, 2, 3]; b = a; a += [4, 5, 6]` and you'll see that `a` and `b` are still the same.)

Answer (score 15):

If you take a look at the [official docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), you'll see right below `append`, `extend`.  That's what your looking for.

There's also [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) if you are more interested in efficient iteration than ending up with a fully populated data structure.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to unpack both lists inside a new list and assign it back to the copy of the original list:

```py
my_list[:] = [*my_list, *new_items]
```

An example:

```
my_list = [1, 2]
new_items = [3, 4, 5]

my_list[:] = [*my_list, *new_items]
my_list                                # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

or assign to an empty slice as in [Saumya Prasad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72623367/19123103) (but at the end of the list):

```py
length = len(my_list)
my_list[length:length] = new_items
my_list                                # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

It's worth noting that `list.extend` and slice assignment to an empty slice both modify the list in-place whereas `itertools.chain` or unpacking or `+` operator create a new list.

Answer (score 1):

if the number of items was saved in a variable say n. you can use list comprehension and plus sign for list expansion.

```
lst = ['A', 'B']
n = 1
new_lst = lst + ['flag'+str(x) for x in range(n)]
print(my_lst)

>>> ['A','B','flag0','flag1']
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you can work around this type of problem is -

Here we are inserting a list to the existing list by creating a variable **new_values**.

Note that we are inserting the values in the *second index*, i.e. **a[2]**

```
a = [1, 2, 7, 8]

new_values = [3, 4, 5, 6]

a.insert(2, new_values)

print(a)
```

But here insert() method will append the values as a list.

So here goes another way of doing the same thing, but this time, we'll actually insert the values in between the items.

```
a = [1, 2, 7, 8]

a[2:2] = [3,4,5,6]

print(a)
```