# Simplifying a few rows of code using a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

While attempting to make a sudoku solving program, I encountered a small problem. That is, the amount of rows (lists) I want to append into a list.

```
# These are the lists that i have to append

row0 = [5,3,0, 0,7,0, 0,0,0]
row1 = [6,0,0, 1,9,5, 0,0,0]
row2 = [0,9,8, 0,0,0, 0,6,0]

row3 = [8,0,0, 0,6,0, 0,0,3]
row4 = [4,0,0, 8,0,3, 0,0,1]
row5 = [7,0,0, 0,2,0, 0,0,6]

row6 = [0,6,0, 0,0,0, 2,8,0]
row7 = [0,0,0, 4,1,9, 0,0,5]
row8 = [0,0,0, 0,8,0, 0,7,9]


# And this, is what i want to avoid doing.

rows.append(row0)
rows.append(row1)
rows.append(row2)

rows.append(row3)
rows.append(row4)
rows.append(row5)

rows.append(row6)
rows.append(row7)
rows.append(row8)
```

Is it possible to append all those lists, with help of a for loop or something similar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append multiple values to a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196159/how-to-append-multiple-values-to-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using nine row variables, you could use one 2D array called "grid".

```
var grid = [[5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0],
            [6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0],
            [0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0],
            [8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3],
            [4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1],
            [7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6],
            [0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0],
            [0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5],
            [0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9]]
```

That way, copying the grid could be done in one line.

Comment: @scharette if it was java or something, he needs a semicolon behind at the end of the whole thing.

Comment: @Forsarna_ The code posted by Alex is valid javascript code due to the `var`

Answer (score 0):

Why not put your original lists in a list of their own so you can iterate over them?

```
# These are the lists that i have to append
rowsToAppend = []
rowsToAppend.append([5,3,0, 0,7,0, 0,0,0])
rowsToAppend.append([6,0,0, 1,9,5, 0,0,0])
# etc...


for row in rowsToAppend:
    rows.append(row)
```

Or of course, you could just immediately define your rows array

```
rows = []
rows.append([5,3,0, 0,7,0, 0,0,0])
rows.append([6,0,0, 1,9,5, 0,0,0])
# etc...
# No need to append since it's already done
```

Comment: Don't you need to use append so you don't get an out of range error?

Comment: @BenJones you are completely correct let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a indirect solution. Consider using 2-D lists, or a matrix. For a 2-D list, see the other answers; for a matrix, see [numpy.matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html).

Essentially, you would have something like this:

```
>>> a = np.matrix('1 2; 3 4')
>>>print(a)
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
```

or

```
>>> np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
matrix([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]])
```

One of the benefits of using the numpy matrix is inputting and outputting is "prettified" as well as access to additional numpy methods and attributes that can be of great use in implementing a suduku game.