# how to put variables 'a', 'b' and 'c' inside list 'Var2'? in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

```
a=0
b=1
c=2
d=3
e=4

Var = [a,b,c,d,e]
Var2 =[]

for i in Var:
    if i <= 2:
    Var2 = [i]
print(Var2)
```

**this is the result**

**[2]**

**Process finished with exit code 0**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append multiple values to a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196159/how-to-append-multiple-values-to-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Replcae `Var2 = [i]` with:

```
Var2 += [i]
```

or you can use `Var2.append(i)`

Answer (score 0):

Use append() function of list.

```
for i in Var:
    if i <= 2:
        Var2.append(i)
print(Var2)
```