# append number of arguments

Tags: python, list, dictionary

we know append can take only one argument but in one course I see append takes three argument card_list.append((i*50,50,card))?

is it possible to have more than 1 argument in python append function

Comment: In this case, `.append` is taking *one*, argument.  It is a single *tuple* of three elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append multiple values to a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196159/how-to-append-multiple-values-to-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
card_list.append((i*50,50,card))
```

function call is `card_list.append()` so what you are appending to the list is

```
(i*50,50,card)
```

You are not appending multiple element at once, but only 1 element that is a tuple (containing multiple element)

Example :

```
card_list = []


card_list.append((10,20,30))
card_list.append((40,50,60))

print(card_list) // prints [(10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60)]
```

you see that inside the list, we have 2 element (2 tuple) of 3 value

if now you do

```
for elem in card_list:
    print(elem)
```

it prints :

```
(10, 20, 30) // element 1
(40, 50, 60) // element 2
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot append 3 arguments at the same time but you can make an argument including the three arguments and then append that single argument into the list

for eg:-

```
list=[]
i=int(input("Enter the number:: "))
card=input("card::")
a=i*50

out=str(a)+","+str(i)+","+card

list.append(out)

print(list)
```

so if we input:

```
Enter the number:: 10
card::card
```

the output will be:

```
['500,10,card']
```

Comment: It must be pointed out that this answer is riddled with poor-practices and inefficiency.  Not sure if this even answers the question; but rather adds parsing complexity to whatever will be reading the list elements later.  Keeping as a list of tuples (as shown in the question) would certainly be preferable to this.

Comment: i know this answer complicates things a bit more, but i just wanted to share the different perspective of the question. I am sorry if its misleading. My Apologies. @S3DEV

Comment: No need for apologies.  You’re free to delete the answer if you choose.