# Issue with appending a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have an empty list `J`. I am writing a loop and want to append based on the `t` values. But I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
J=[]

for t in range(0,1):
    J[t]=[[1,3,5]]
    J[t+1]=[[1,3]]
    J.append([[J[t]],[J[t+1]]])
print(J)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    J[t]=[[1,3,5]]

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

The expected output is

```
[[1,3,5],[1,3]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append multiple values to a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196159/how-to-append-multiple-values-to-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

By specifying `J[t] = [...]` you are trying to assign the array to `J[t]` which doesn't exist yet.

You are also then trying to take list items and add them back into the list again; even if `J[t] = [...]` were working, this would double up your results.

Instead, try this:

```py
J=[]

for t in range(0,1):
    J.append([1,3,5])
    J.append([1,3])

print(J)
```

This produces your expected result.

It's worth noting that `for t in range(0,1)` is meaningless, as `t` will only ever be zero; If you change to `range(0,2)` you would get:

`[[1,3,5],[1,3],[1,3,5],[1,3]]` which may be what you're after? It's difficult ascertain why you are using the for loop from your example.

Comment: I want to use the loop because eventually I want to obtain output for many ```t``` say, ```100```. How do I write the loop accurately?

Comment: `range(x,y)` produces a list ranging from `x` up to *but not including* `y`, So if you wanted `t` to range from 0 to 100, you would use `for t in range(0,101):`

Answer (score 1):

In the `for` loop when `t==0`, you try to access the index `t` in `J`, which comes down to `J[0]`, however `J` is `[]`, which doesn't have an index-able entry `0`.

If you want `[[1,3,5],[1,3]]` as the output, using a `for` loop, have a look at Mureinik's answer, or consider:

```py
J    = []
odds = [1,3,5]

for t in range(0,2):
    J.append(odds[:(len(odds))-t])

print(J)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a value to an index of the list that isn't there yet. `J` is initialized as an empty list, so by definition it has no indexes, and any assignment to any index will result in an `IndexError`. Instead, you should just append to it:

```py
J.append([1,3,5]) # Index 0
J.append([1,3])   # Index 1
```

Comment: You can, however, assign to a slice that's not there yet: `J[t:] = [[1,3,5]]` which is only a one-bit modification of the OP's code and may have been what he was aiming for.