# how to store the user input in a list?

Tags: python

Code example:

```
Fruit= 'maça',

user_imput= input(str('insert a fruit: '))


if user_imput in Fruit:
  print('fruit already in list')
if user_imput not in Fruit:
  print('fruit not in list')
```

if the user input is in the list, it will print that is already in the list.
if not will print that is not in the list, but I want to put the input in the list if it is not.
I already tried `.append`

Comment: You don't _have_ a list, the value of `Fruit` is a _string_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is a tuple, no? `Fruit= 'maça',`

Comment: You can't modify a tuple. You should make it a list, then you can use `Fruit.append(user_imput)` to add to it.

Comment: Yes it is a tuple.  But if you want to add items to it, a list would be better.  `Fruit = ['maça']`

Comment: Also the second `if` condition can just be `else:`.

Comment: Oh you're right @OneCricketeer, missed the `,`. The error would have made that clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append multiple values to a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196159/how-to-append-multiple-values-to-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change Fruit to a list, then append input:

```
Fruit = ['maça']

user_input = input(str('insert a fruit: '))
Fruit.append(user_input)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I already tried `.append`

And what error did you get? Something like this?

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Use a `set` to prevent duplicates or an actual list, not a tuple.

```
fruit = set(['maça'])

user_input = input('insert a fruit: ')

if user_input in fruit:
  print('fruit already in list')
else:
  print('fruit not in list')
  fruit.add(user_input)
```

Comment: im not getting any error now, but also dont update the list

Comment: It should since it is working for me. Have you tried to `print(fruit)`?